# How is $x^2$ related to $x^Tx$

Tags: vectors, transpose

If $x$ is a column vector how is $x^2$ related to $x^\top x$?

Where $x^\top$ is the transpose of $x$.

Comment: If $x$ is a column vector, $x^2$ doesn't make sense....

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking which is why I asked the question, but the_candyman's answer explains it, my lecturer has a bad habit of writing $x^2$ instead of $||x||^2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\|x\|$ be the norm-2 (euclidean norm) of $x$. Then:

$$x^\top x = \|x\|^2.$$

Someone has the **bad habit** to assume $x^2 = \|x\|^2$, but it is not rigorously correct.

Comment: It have seen sometimes a bad habit to write $x^2=\langle x,x\rangle$, that is square in the scalar product sense. I do not like it either, but it makes some more sense than $\|x\|^2$ (though it is the same in the Hilbert norm).

Comment: @A.G. To be honest, what I have seen is $$x^2 = \langle {\bf x}, {\bf x} \rangle.$$ Definitely, bold face ${\bf x}$ denotes the vector, while $x$ denotes the euclidean norm $\|{\bf x}\| = {\bf x}^{\top} {\bf x}$. It is a question of notation. Generally, this is used by physicists.

Comment: Allright, it is like $r$ and $\mathbf{r}$ in vector calculus.

Answer (score 0):

But in the above solution, $x^{\perp}x=\lVert x\rVert^2$, LHS is a matrix and RHS is a number.

How can they be equated?

Answer (score 0):

Let $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $ \left \| \cdot  \right \| $ be the euclidean norm,
$ \left \| x \right \|^2 = < x, x > = ^tx \cdot x $